# Postgres libpq call PQfinish crash

Tags: c#, postgresql, interop

```
[DllImport("libpq", EntryPoint = "PQfinish", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    internal static extern void PQfinish(IntPtr connection);
    private static void Close(IntPtr connection)
    {
        PQfinish(connection);
    }
```

I have this iterop code to call PQfinish from my asp.net dot net core when trying to close connection with postgreSQL database.

For unknown reason, it maybe work one time, then it crash and making the whole website stop working.

I can open connection, execute query, retrieve result without any problem at all. Only calling PQfinish always crashing.

PostgreSQL 9.5 x64

Comment: You can be pretty sure `connection' is invalid. A bit more code would help.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue with our libpq wrapper for c++.

It looked like it was crashing on the PQfinish call but it was due to the fact that we were returning the PGresult of the query after we had used PQclear on that result (and so freeing the PGresult).

When later we wanted to use the PGresult the app crashed.

Our solution was to return a string copied from the PGresult before freeing it with PQclear.

Check if you are not doing something like that.